Error converting Spark DataFrame to pandas: Py4JException Method pandasStructHandlingMode does not exist
I am attempting to convert a Spark DataFrame to a pandas DataFrame and then save it to a CSV file using PySpark within an Anaconda environment. However, I encounter a Py4JException error stating that the method pandasStructHandlingMode does not exist. Below are the versions of the tools and libraries I am using:

Python Version: 3.10.14 (Anaconda)
PySpark Version: 3.5.1
Py4J Version: 0.10.9.7
Apache Spark Version: 3.4.3
Apache Arrow Version: 14.0.2
Operating System: Windows 11

Here is the relevant part of the code:
try:
    df_pandas = df_spark.toPandas()
except Exception as e:
    print("Error converting to pandas:", e)

And this is the full error message I receive:
py4j.Py4JException: Method pandasStructHandlingMode([]) does not exist
...

I have tried checking the Apache Arrow configuration to ensure it is enabled, but the error persists. Can anyone help me understand why this error occurs and how I can resolve it?
I have tried the following to resolve the issue:

Changing Python Versions: I switched to different versions of Python within my Anaconda environment, including Python 3.8, but the issue persisted.
Reinstalling Libraries: I reinstalled both pyspark and py4j using pip.
Restarting: I restarted my system and the Anaconda environment multiple times to ensure all changes took effect.


can you show the output of df_spark.printSchema() ?

root
|-- FirstName: string (nullable = true)
|-- LastName: string (nullable = true)

I found a solution to this problem. It seems that PySpark version 3.5.1 has a compatibility issue with converting to pandas. Changing the PySpark version to 3.4.0 resolved the issue for me. Here are the steps I followed:

Uninstall the current version of PySpark:
pip uninstall pyspark


Install PySpark version 3.4.0:
pip install pyspark==3.4.0



After doing this, the code worked correctly, and I was able to convert the Spark DataFrame to pandas without any issues.

I experienced this error for some time while trying to convert a pyspark dataframe to a pandas dataframe.
I am using pyspark version 3.5.3
This was my solution.
#imports
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
import pandas as pd
```python
pandas_df = pyspark_df.select('column_1', 'column_2', 'column_3___').filter(col("filter_column") == "some_value").limit(10000).collect()

#NOTE: Mine has a filter since I had to filter the data
#then convert to pandas dataframe using pd.DataFrame method
filtered_df = pd.DataFrame(df, columns=['column_1', 'column_2', 'column_3---'])

Thank you. I hope that helps.
